# Don't know how to protect the command from people without a role Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to limit a command to only @Narrator users, nothing I have seen works, always throw

```
TypeError: message.member.roles.has is not a function //Have tried by id and name, nothing works
```

I've used with .has .find .some and many different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you need to use the `cache` property to access a GuildMember's roles

```js
message.member.roles.cache.has()
```

Comment: This is the solution!  But I got another question, can you answer it too pls?

Comment: Try and specify one question per question. If you have another question that's fine, but open it up as a new one. Also, if an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked and that the question was answered.